# How to find out why gazelle is adding a specific dependency?

Tags: bazel, gazelle

We have proto files that `import "google/api/annotations.proto";`. I'm adding `# gazelle:resolve proto go google/api/annotations.proto @org_golang_google_genproto//googleapis/api/annotations` to some `BUILD` files but `gazelle` is still adding `"@go_googleapis//google/api:annotations_go_proto"` as a `dep` to `go_library` rules.

How do I find out why `gazelle` is doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs for directives: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-gazelle#directives

> import-lang is the language importing the library. This is usually the same as source-lang but may differ with generated code. For example, when resolving dependencies for a go_proto_library, source-lang would be "proto" and import-lang would be "go". import-lang may be omitted if it is the same as source-lang.

Since you have your import-lang set to `go`, Its picking up the name of the rule defining the `go_proto_library` in the repo:

https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/9f7c0ffdaa8ceb2f27982bad713a03306157a4d2/google/api/BUILD.bazel#L345